# Initialize members of a struct to zero via the struct pointer

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct

```
typedef struct {  
double firstArray[3];
double secondArray[4][4];
bool   thirdArray[2];    
} myStruct;
```

I understand that we can initialize all values of an array to zero in one line using `int myArray[10] = { 0 };`

I have a function to initialize all elements of the arrays in myStruct to zero & false (for bool).

```
void initializeElementsOfStruct(myStruct* str)
{
str->firstArray[0] = 0.0;
str->firstArray[1] = 0.0;
str->firstArray[2] = 0.0;
...
}
```

Instead of the above or using for loops, how do I do it in one liners?

Edit: The struct may contain non primitive datatypes too.

Comment: Ah, you've changed the question *and* the language. That's mildly frustrating, but could you at least create a representative example (i.e. an example problem whose solution would also solve your real problem)?

Comment: Language was changed by the moderator

Comment: I see, that's not cool. Please feel free to change it back!

Comment: How about allocating memory at run-time with calloc()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you struct only consists of primitive types, you can set its entire memory representation to zero and should get the desired effect. (This may potentially overwrite padding bytes which you wouldn't be writing to in your member-wise approach, but that may actually be *more* efficient in the end.)

In C:

```
#include <string.h>

memset(str, 0, sizeof *str)
```

In C++:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::fill(reinterpret_cast<char*>(str),
          reinterpret_cast<Char*>(str) + sizeof *str, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that the struct may have non primitive types too. I have added this line in the question now.

Comment: `memory.h`? Maybe you meant `string.h`.

Comment: @user694733: You're right. I thought `memory.h` was standard, but it seems to just be a GCC thing.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Would memset still work if the array was an enum type?

Comment: @ontherocks: It should, since enums are integral types. I can't think of a situation where the zero value would *not* be represented by a zero byte pattern.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic solution, backward compatible with C89/90 is

```
void initializeElementsOfStruct(myStruct* str)
{
  const myStruct ZERO = { 0 };
  *str = ZERO;
}
```

For "stupid" compilers in it might make sense to declare `ZERO` as `static` (in performance-critical code).

In C99 you can simply do

```
void initializeElementsOfStruct(myStruct* str)
{
  *str = (myStruct) { 0 };
}
```

A fairly equivalent C++ version (which is aware of C++ specific initialization semantics) will look as

```
void initializeElementsOfStruct(myStruct* str)
{
  *str = myStruct();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you can define a helper function like this:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value, T>::type>
void zero_initialize(T &x) {
  std::memset(&x, 0, sizeof(x));
}
```

It will work only for POD types and fail to compile otherwise.

```
void initializeElementsOfStruct(myStruct* str) {
  zero_initialize(*str);
}
```